# How to add unit test To ADO.Net Generic Data Access Layer

Tags: sql-server, unit-testing, c#-4.0, ado.net, data-access-layer

I m developping a generic ADO.net DAL and I want to add some unit tests. I need to find a way how to test for example an insert query is there a good tutorial or blog to do such a thing.

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Microsoft's Data Access Application Block](http://daab.codeplex.com/) is a generic ADO.Net DAL. It's source code is available on CodePlex along with Unit Tests. Even if you write your own, you can use it as a guide, or any other OpenSource micro-ORM. Most micro-ORM projects worth their salt come with Unit Tests.

[Updated github link to original codeplex project](https://github.com/microsoftarchive/data-access-application-block) Thank you @ZeRemz

Comment: The link provided in this answer is dead
I assume this git repo is a mirror/equivalent of the original CodePlex project ? https://github.com/microsoftarchive/data-access-application-block

Comment: @ZeRemz Yes! It is the correct updated link. Back in 2015 CodePlex was still a thing. And thank you, I've wanted an updated link to the DAAB, if nothing else for nostalgia's sake. I refer to this pre-EF code base often when discussing data driven architectures.